# The layout breaks when the keypad pops up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The layout breaks when I select the textbox on the screen. How can it possible to make the screen scrollable with the stack

[image]

Is there any way to scroll the entire content to the bottom when users start typing in the textbox

The code : [Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shyjuzz/2a14a4d334543e1e57d983360272b8e2/raw/58d1133a4e6fa1ccceed8426a347253fb804e271/checkincode.dart)

Comment: Put the content into a SingleChildScrollView

Comment: But I need the "OR" button in the middle of the 2 portions and the submit button at the bottom of the screen, so used the stack. Kindly have a look at the code

Comment: Then put the Stack into the scroll view.

Comment: that didn't work Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the **Stack in the wrong place**.
You need to use the Stack in the upper(scanPortion) widget.
The CircleAvatar should overlap the scanPortion and **make the overflow visible**. This way the CircleAvatar will be stuck to scanPortion and will scroll along with it.

Remove the CircleAvatar from the current place and change the scanPortion into following:

```
var scanPortion = new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 40,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: new Color(0xFF4A4A4C).withOpacity(0.5),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          qrCode,
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          new RaisedButton.icon(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            onPressed: () async {},
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.camera_alt,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: Text('Scan'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 40.0) - 20.0,
      left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) / 2 - 20.0,
      child: Center(
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          child: Text('OR'),
          radius: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
  overflow: Overflow.visible,
);
```

**Later remove the older Stack carefully, as it wont be of any use.**

Comment: It works, Thank you very much. Is there any way to place the submit button at the bottom without the stack ?

Comment: Yes, use Flexible and Button in a Column. Put your scanPortion & manualEntryPortion in Flexible.


`Column(
    Flexible(
        ListView(
            scanPortion
            manualEntryPortion
        )
    )
    Container(
        FlatButton()
    )
)`

Comment: Perfect, Saved my day